# Yum Cannot Retrieve Repository CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos, yum, package-management, repository

I just installed CentOS 6. I tried running yum update and was having trouble getting that to work, so I tried yum clean all and now my situation seems even worse than before. Based upon what I pasted below, can someone please help me fix my yum repository? Thanks.

```
[root@zedo-pc 1234]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.7x24web.net
 * extras: mirror.linux.duke.edu
 * updates: mirror.lug.udel.edu
Error: no such table: packages

[root@zedo-pc 1234]# yum clean all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Cleaning up Everything
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors

[root@zedo-pc 1234]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirror.lug.udel.edu
 * extras: mirror.symnds.com
 * updates: mirror.rackspace.com
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: InstallMedia. Please verify its path and try again
```

Comment: Please include the Yum repository file.  Just a hunch though, but each time you run yum, you get a different mirror.  Maybe there are a few bad/misconfigured mirrors in there?  How many times have you ran it?

Also, you should be able to reach those mirrors via http.  Can you try plugging them into your web browser?

Comment: Have you verified that both Internet (read networking) connectivity and name resolution are working properly?

Comment: Where is the yum repository file you speak of located? It seems that the mirrors changed as a result of me running yum clean all.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff - I'm not quite sure what you are suggesting that I check. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Perhaps you could post the content of /etc/yum.conf, or the output of ls /etc/yum.repos.d. Another handy thing would be to mention any proxy setup etc you use.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. All I did was renew my `dhcp` (`dhcp -r`) and it worked. I noticed the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` had been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Once you run `yum clean all`, try running  `yum makecache`. Also check which repositories are enabled now (not that conf files could be goofed up) `yum repolist`

Comment: >>Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: InstallMedia. Please verify its path and try again
This definitely looks a goofup in the configuration file to me. Identify the rogue configuration file with pattern /installmedia/i

Answer (score 0):

`Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: InstallMedia. Please verify its path and try again`
This might indicate you have a repository configured and enabled that is looking for a local CD/DVD/ISO.

You can try to disable all repositories and enable them one by one to identify which one is causing the problem.

`yum repolist all` will identify all of the repositories configured.

`yum check-update --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=<reponame>` Disables all repositories except the one (or ones) listed with `--enablerepo` (which can be specified multiple times).

You need to identify which repositories is causing the issue, then check that repositories configuration (in `/etc/yum.conf` or `/etc/yum.repos.d/`).  If you need help with that post the relevant configuration.